# Spring Boot can't find bean despite the package being on component scan

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring-Boot does not find the bean, even though I added the explicit package to the ComponentScan. It's not profile restricted, and I added a @Repository annotation.

Exception showing SpringBoot is not able to find bean.

```
2021-05-27 02:25:39 DEBUG o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.CostDataRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1716)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1272)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application.SscFileGeneratorWebApplication.main(SscFileGeneratorWebApplication.java:26)
```

SscFileGeneratorWebApplication.java

```
package com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
         ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class
        })
@ComponentScan({"com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.generator"
,"com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.configuration"
,"com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model"
,"com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.infrastructure.persistence.file.system"
,"com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application"})
public class SscFileGeneratorWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is to fix the reloader bug in DevTools of Spring Boot
        System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");
        SpringApplication.run(SscFileGeneratorWebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

CostDataRepository.java

```
package com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CostDataRepository extends CrudRepository<CostData, Long> {

    List<CostData> findByCostDataIdGreaterThanOrderByCostDataIdAsc(Long lastId);
}
```

GenerateFileService.java

```
package com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application;

import java.util.List;
import com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application.util.LogLayer;
import com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application.util.LogType;
import com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.application.util.LogUtils;
import com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.configuration.FileGeneratorProperties;
import com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.CostData;
import com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.CostDataRepository;
import com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.SSCFileDescriptor;
import com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.csv.CsvFileGenerator;
import com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model.ebcdic.EBCDICFileGenerator;
import com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.infrastructure.persistence.file.system.FileWriter;
import com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.infrastructure.port.email.EmailService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.process.model.LastRunResult;
import com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.process.model.RunResult;
import com.mycomp.proj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.process.model.RunResultService;

@Service
public class GenerateFileService {
    private CostDataRepository costDataRepository;
    private FileWriter fileWriter;
    private final FileGeneratorProperties properties;
    private static final String CREATE_FILES = "CREATE_FILES";
    private Logger logger;
    private final ObjectFactory<SSCFileDescriptor> fileDescriptorFactory;
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private RunResultService runResultService;
    private EmailService emailService;

    @Autowired
    public GenerateFileService(CostDataRepository costDataRepository, FileWriter fileWriter, FileGeneratorProperties properties,
                               ObjectFactory<SSCFileDescriptor> fileDescriptorFactory,
                               BeanFactory beanFactory, RunResultService runResultService,
                               EmailService emailService) {
        this.costDataRepository = costDataRepository;
        this.fileWriter = fileWriter;
        this.properties = properties;
        this.fileDescriptorFactory = fileDescriptorFactory;
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
        this.runResultService = runResultService;
        this.emailService = emailService;
    }
    ...


}
```

Comment: Note that `@ComponentScan` automatically includes subpackages, so you don't need most of the list there. The package for `CostDataRepository` is also a mismatch; guessing that that was a redaction oversight, you need `@EnableJpaRepositories` (presumably), not `@ComponentScan`.

Comment: seem you are missing add com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.domain.model into ComponentScan?

Comment: Possibly `@Repository` isn't enough because `CostDataRepository` is only an interface but you need to `Autowire` an implementation. Guess you need another Annotation like @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic also mentioned.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I corrected the package name typo, everything should be com.mycomp.proj.

Comment: Also tried adding @EnableJpaRepositories, but it still gave me the same error. What gets me is that I have something very similar in a different repository that Spring is happy with. Then I specified the package name to EnableJpaRepositories and it says "Not a managed type ...CostData"

Comment: @Ogod Even `@Repository` is unnecessary; repository interfaces are automatically implemented by Spring Data at runtime.

Comment: I am wondering about the method `findByCostDataIdGreaterThanOrderByCostDataIdAsc` in your `CostDataRepository` interface. Where is this one implemented? Spring couldn't do the implementation for this method for you, because it don't know what is your business logic for this use case. What happens if you comment this method and it's usages and then try do restart? Does it work?

Comment: @Ogod Actually, JPA figures this out in some cryptic, Java Reflection type way. It actually works if I run this as a Spring batch oriented program.

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware of this. Maybe you can enable some debug logging of the spring framework to understand what is happening behind the scenes? There are already answers for this on stackoverflow which you can try. And I would suggest that you add some more tags like JPA, autowire so that some experts may find your question.